# UIWebView Javascript Window to Window Communication

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, xcode

I'm working on an iOS app in which I'm trying to use `UIWebView` to display a variety of websites. Recently I finished logic to inject Javascript into the `UIWebView` to catch instances of `window.open`, `window.close`, and `window.opener.focus`. In short, to do so, I inject JS that overrides the aforementioned JS functions, which includes creating an `iframe` with a specific scheme that I can catch in the app's `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` method. This is all working OK for now, including `window.open` creating a new `UIWebView` rather than loading in the same window.

Now though, the issue has come up where there's no feasible solution for JS communication between windows. If the child window tries to call to `window.opener` or `window.parent`, it's always returning a null value, and thus, it can't communicate back to the original web view.

In an effort to see what iOS browsers are able to effectively perform window-to-window communication, I found that of the 9 browsers I have on my iPhone, only Safari was able to effectively perform this communication successfully. This leads me to believe that there's something with `UIWebView` that prevents full JS window-to-window communication from being possible.

Has anyone had any success with getting UIWebView to fully integrate with all JS logic, namely window-to-window communication? Or have proof that JS window-to-window communication isn't possible? Any direction or advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue. Any luck?

Comment: No luck yet, unfortunately. All I've been able to do is simple JS injection to override window methods (mentioned above). In my case, the core issue stemmed from Facebook authentication in the website loaded into the UIWebview, where the user would get stuck after authenticating, because there was no window-to-window communication. In the end, I had to change the logic in the website loaded into the WebView (which I happened to have the ability to control), to use a direct re-direct to FB rather than using the normal auth flow with a popup window.

Answer (score 1):

Found possible solution.

Add JavaScriptCore.framework to Linked Frameworks and in your webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
JSContext *parentCtx = [self.parentWebView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
JSContext *childCtx = [self.childWebView  valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
childCtx[@"window"][@"opener"] = parentCtx[@"window"];
```

Now when you call window.opener.test() from childWebView, it will fire test function in parentWebView!

I'm not sure about private API.
Works on iOS 7 only

Comment: Why you say it´s only for IOS 7? I´m trying to achieve this in IOS 9! Any idea?

Comment: iOS 7 was the latest one at that moment :)

Answer (score 0):

Swift version

```
    import JavaScriptCore

    let jsContextA = webA.valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext")
    let jsContextB = webB.valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext")        

    //Original objc code : jsContextB[@"window"][@"opener"] = jsContextA[@"window"];
    jsContextB!.setObject("opener", forKeyedSubscript: "window")
    jsContextB!.setObject(jsContextA!.objectForKeyedSubscript("window"), forKeyedSubscript: "opener")
```