# UIWebView and javascript window.opener

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, window.opener

Let us say one UIWebView runs javascript code using window.open() to open a new window. Let's say I override window.open() to communicate with native code and open a separate UIWebView. Now I want those two web views to communicate in javascript through window.opener. How is this possible?

Comment: Same problem here! Any luck?

Comment: Found the way out.
Checkout my answer on here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20663261/1245134